# Передача информации из Activity в Service

Tags: java, android, service

Я знаю, что передать данные в сервис можно через intent, но насколько я понял в intent мы данные кладем до старта Service, а после в Service мы работаем с уже имеющимися в intent данными. Отправку данных из Service в Activity я настроил с помощью Handler, а как сделать отправку данных из Activity уже после запуска?

Answer (score 5):

Точно также можно использовать команду startService применительно к уже работающему сервису и обработать эти данные в onStartCommand сервиса.

Код в активити:

```
// Хотим передать значение таймаута в сервис
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra(MyService.PARAM_TIMEOUT, 500);
startService(intent);
```

Код в сервисе:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            timeout = intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_TIMEOUT, 600);
        }
}
```

Но если данных много и с сервисом надо плотно общаться, то имеет смысл создать соединение с сервисом и получить сам объект сервиса через интерфейс Binder. Однако непонятно, насколько это необходимо в вашем случае.

Comment: В сервисе я хотел реализовать Socket client который не только получает данные, но и отправляет их обратно, а полученные\отправленные данные должны отображаться на Activity. В таком случае мне необходимо чере Bind?

Comment: Зависит от архитектуры приложения и того, что именно вам требуется, нужно понимать контекст. Может быть, вполне хватит передачи данных в сервис через startService и возврат ответа обратно в активити через BroadcastReceiver, зарегистрированный в сервисе. А может быть, и не хватит. Но мне кажется, это уже отдельная тема, и лучше создать отдельный вопрос, в котором более подробно сформулировать задачи.