# Реализовать плотное общение между Activity и Service

Tags: java, android, service, клиент-сервер

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но мне посоветовали задать новый уточняя, что мне требуется в задаче. Ну так вот:

Пробую свои силы в клиент-серверах. Подключение клиента реализовывал в AsyncTask, который получается привязан к одному Activity.

Тут мне посоветовали использовать Service или Singleton AsyncTask. С синглетоном все получилось и вот теперь разбираюсь с Service.

Тут я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: взаимодействие между Activity и Service. Нашел несколько решений, но некоторые я реализовать не смог, другие не выполняют задумку в полной степени, а именно: необходимо, что бы client реализованный в Service подключался по полученному из Activity IP и PORT, после чего клиент получает сигнал с сервера и должен сменить Activity, далее в новом Activity должно быть плотное общение с Service (*реализация отправки данных из Activity в Service, а от туда по сокету на сервер, и наоборот*).

Так вот в чем вопрос. **Как мне правильно реализовать такой механизм?**

Для передачи данных из Service, я воспользовался Handler и через Messenger отправляю данные, но как отправлять данные из Activity я так и не понял.
Если через Intent, который мы передаем в startCommand, то не слишком ли это громоздкая передача получается?

Comment: поиск по сайту -> activity service -> 10 вопросов с ответами на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стандартным способом реализации "плотного" общения `Activity` и `Service` является процедура биндинга, в результате которого получается [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) - связанный сервис.

Обычно во многих туториалах реализации сервисов метод `onBind()` вашего `Service` возвращает `null`, а между тем, есть случаи когда `onBind()` должен реально работать.

С точки зрения программиста, после реализации биндинга у вас должен остаться указатель на экземпляр `Service` привязанного `Activity`, с которым уже можно делать вполне обычные манипуляции - типа вызвать методы сервиса, передающие или получающие некие параметры/переменные.

За примером [втыкать сюда](http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/)

Comment: к сожалению не знаю как можно было бы с вами связаться, хотел совета от вас. Просто совет короткий, после которого я буду долго и упорно идти к гуру.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask для такого решения крайне неудачен. Всегда такого рода задачи необходимо исполнять в Service, но будьте внимательны, сервис работает в основном UI потоке, поэтому все длительные операции выполняйте в другом, а иначе схватите **Application Not Responding**. Для передачи инфы в Service используйте, как вы уже написали, **startCommand** (нет, не громоздкая), а для передачи инфы из сервиса в Activity можете реализовать через **BroadCastReceiver**, т.е. в Activity вы регистрируете **BroadCastReceiver**, задаёте ему свой **Action** для фильтра, а далее из Service можете отсылать сообщения через **BroadCastReceiver**, но помните, что тот же **BroadCastReceiver** тоже работает в UI потоке.

Comment: что за ерунду Вы пишете - `но будьте внимательны, сервис работает в основном UI потоке`...почитайте документацию

Comment: @ermak0ff А может это вы ерунду пишете. Раз вы такой умный, то пожалуйста ссылку в студию на описание сервиса, которое может подтвердить ваши слова

Comment: да не вопрос, первое предложение - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Вот вы и облажались, там ясно написано про предупреждение.

Comment: Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.

Comment: `A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. `

Comment: АА, всё ясно, у вас пригорели от UI, что ж, тут я был некорректен, я имел ввиду, что сервис работает в **Главном потоке** , а не то, что он взаимодействует с UI

Comment: у BroadCastReceiver-ов своя задача, а использовать их повсеместно (тем более посредником между activity и service)  - это плохая практика

Comment: Но всё же можно, а что не запрещено, то разрешено. И назовите причину, почему же это плохо, могут возникнуть какие-то проблемы? Лично я их не вижу. Видимо вы видите проблему в том, что задав какой-нибудь Action, который используется в других прилагах может возникнуть конфликт? Но если всё делать правильно, но и проблем не будет

Comment: я не вижу надобности использовать более ресурсозатратный для системы подход, коим является  BroadCastReceiver, если есть уже реализованный и продуманный функционал, им же является Binder

Comment: Тут вы абсолютно правы, Binder идеальный случай для этого. Вот 2 ссылки с примеро:1)http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/163-urok-98-service-lokalnyj-binding.html  2)http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection.html

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи данных в сервис вам вполне подойдет startCommand, это не громоздкий механизм, хотя и странный на первый взгляд. Пример кода в моем ответе на первый вопрос ([Передача информации из Activity в Service](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455896/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-activity-%D0%B2-service/456002#456002)). 
Для передачи данных из сервиса в активити в вашем случае можно попробовать использовать BroadcastReceiver.
Код в активити:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "action_session_closed";
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Обработчик получения сообщений от сервиса сессии
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            // действия при получении сообщений - тут мы получаем сообщение о том, что сессия завершилась
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                boolean sessionClosed = intent.getBooleanExtra("sessionClosed", false);
                // Мы получили сообщение о завершении сессии, можем обрабатывать его как хотим
            }
        };
        // создаем фильтр для BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter intFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        // регистрируем (включаем) BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // дерегистрируем (выключаем) BroadcastReceiver
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Код в сервисе, вызывается в момент, когда надо передать данные наружу:

```
/**
 * Отправка сообщения о закрытии сессии
 */
private void sendCloseSessionMessage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("sessionClosed", true);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Я сейчас описываю только передачу данных между сервисом и активити, работу с тасками намеренно не затрагиваю.
Если же данного механизма окажется недостаточно, то выше правильно ответили - нужно будет использовать механизм биндинга сервиса, получать его эеземпляр в активити и дальше напрямую работать с ним.