# Как обновлять seekbar, если воспроизведение идет из Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

```
public class PlayMusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener 
{
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int icon = R.drawable.play;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       // mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);// raw/s.mp3
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Value.songUrl.get(Value.currentSongIndex));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Notification notification = new android.app.Notification(icon, "OnWave", when);
        //Создание намерения с указанием класса вашей Activity, которую хотите вызвать при           нажатии на оповещение.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Исполнитель", "Название", contentIntent);
        startForeground(1, notification);
      /*  if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

            mediaPlayer.start();
        }*/
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Value.currentSongPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
        this.stopForeground(false);
    }

    public static void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
       Value.currentSongPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.songPositionBar.setProgress(Value.currentSongPosition);
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            MainActivity.songPositionBar.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        MainActivity.songPositionBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        mp.seekTo(Value.currentSongPosition);
        mp.start();
        Value.currentSongPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        startPlayProgressUpdater();
    }
}
```

Когда нажимаю плей все работает, но стоит нажать стоп и приложение крашится

Comment: На какой строчке ошибка появляется? Где и как вы стоп нажимаете? Информации недостаточно для ответа

Comment: нажимаю стоп через stopservice, т.е. вызываю метод onDestroy

Comment: А на какой строчке и какая ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка на рекурсивном вызове метода startPlayProgressUpdater(), причем на первой строке, чтобы там не было написано, всегда ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему (хотя вы и упорно не раскрываете что у вас за ошибка и в как вы вызываете метод, её вызывающий) у вас NPE при попытке обращения к переменной сервиса в статическом методе из активити.

Вы изначально неверно понимаете способы общения сервиса и активити. Вам надо из активити получить экземпляр работающего сервиса. Делать это надо через `Binder`. Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456183/17609) [тут](http://startofandroid.com/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection.html) и в гугле.

Пихать медиаплеер в статическое поле сервиса - точно не надо.

---

**UPD_0:**

В данном случае ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к MediaPlayer после вызова release(). В документации сказано, что после этого вызова объект плеера уже не доступен по этой ссылке и его надо переинициализировать. А в вашем случае надо его в null обратить и проверять на null перед дальнейшими попытками взаимодействия.

Comment: playbackServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PlayMusicService.class);
 startService(playbackServiceIntent);
stopService(playbackServiceIntent);

Comment: Вот так я обращаюсь к сервису из активити

Comment: Вы говорите, что падаем при попытке остановить сервис и вы же говорите, что падает при вызове startPlayProgressUpdater, коий не вызывается в onDestroy. Я запутался.

Comment: если честно не понял)
когда я нажимаю плей, стартует сервис, идет музыка и бежит ползунок, как только я жму стоп выскакивает ошибка на 
 public void run() {

                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
Зачем мне ее вызывать в дестрой?)

Comment: Какая ошибка-то? StackTace в вопросе приведите...

Comment: Видать у вас mediaPlayer после вызова `relese()` не может никаких вызовов принимать и потому и падает... А вообще архитектура взаимодействия серсис-активити у вас в корне неправильная. Вам надо всё переделывать.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalStateException" - этого мало, но даже это подтверждает моё предположение.

Comment: После relese() добавьте ещё mediaPlayer = null; и проверяйте плеер на null в вашем методе startPlayProgressUpdater перед попыткой продолжения его исполнения.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало)))

Comment: Пожалуйста) Вот вам пара советов бесплатных: почитайте по ссылкам как связывать сервис с активити; почитайте местную (этого сайта) справку о том как правильно вопросы задавать (если бы сразу сказали, что у вас illegalState при попытке обратиться к плееру после его release(), то мы бы с вами гоаздо быстрее решили проблему.)

Comment: @DayDreamer, и если ответ решил проблему, то его следует отметить "верным" галочкой слева от тела ответа.